# Page visibility detection - don't know how to set the initial state

Tags: javascript, socket.io, dom-events

I am setting up nodejs/socket.io private messaging between two users. Everything is working as desired but the only problem is to show read receipts of the messages.

As I understand, the only way how to do this is to detect if the message has appeared on the screen of the recipient. So, I want to emit a socket.io event when message appears on the screen of the recipient:

```
socket.emit('messages read', user);
```

All together:

```
var newmessages = 0;

socket.emit("chat message", data); //sending message
newmessages = 1;


function onVisibilityChange(callback) {
    var visible = true;

    if (!callback) {
        throw new Error('no callback given');
    }
    function focused() {
        if (!visible) {
            callback(visible = true);
        }
    }

    function unfocused() {
        if (visible) {
            callback(visible = false);
        }
    }

    if ('hidden' in document) {
        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange',
            function() {(document.hidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
    }
    if ('mozHidden' in document) {
        document.addEventListener('mozvisibilitychange',
            function() {(document.mozHidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
    }
    if ('webkitHidden' in document) {
        document.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange',
            function() {(document.webkitHidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
    }
    if ('msHidden' in document) {
        document.addEventListener('msvisibilitychange',
            function() {(document.msHidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
    }

    if ('onfocusin' in document) {
        document.onfocusin = focused;
        document.onfocusout = unfocused;
    }

    window.onpageshow = window.onfocus = focused;
    window.onpagehide = window.onblur = unfocused;
};

onVisibilityChange(function(visible) {

    if (visible == true) { //here I want to send read confirmation when message appears on the screen
        if (newmes != '0') {
            socket.emit('messages read', user);
            newmessages = 0;
        }
    }

});
```

**The problem**

It works but I don't know how to set the initial state of the visible window. For example, user A is chatting with user B and both users have chat windows opened. The will never get read receipts if continue chatting without switching browser tabs or minimizing the browser that will change the visibility. How can I set `visible` to `true` when users first time load page with chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) to do that. The `load` event is fired when the page loads, so you can set your initial state in this event handler.

```
var visible;

window.onload = function() {
  // Set your initial state.
  visible = true;
};
```

Comment: It works but it always stays "vsible = true" after visibility change

Comment: @Verode - Okay, can you update the question with the your current code? Looks like something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: I accepted your answer, yes, it works. The problem is different. When user A sends message to user B and user's B window is not active, in the moment when message arrives, function set's it to "visible=true" despite the fact that window is not visible and the sender get's read receipt. Don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Verode - When you are setting `visible=true`, only set if the window is active (check if the document is hidden, like you are doing in this question). Also, use another variable such as `messageReceived` as a flag and set it to true when message arrives. When user visits the page again, in focus event handler, check if  `messageReceived` is true and set `visible=true`.

Comment: That's great. Happy to help.